# React Hooks Missing dependency by useMemo after fetching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating `useMyData` hook which does the followings:

1. Fetches raw data from some API based on its input arguments (`dependencies`)
2. Transforms the data using an expensive function (`expensiveMath`)
3. Memoizes and returns the result

My function looks like this:

```
function useMyData(...dependencies) {
  const raw = useFetch(mkUrl(dependencies), dependencies)
  const data = useMemo(() => expensiveMath(raw), dependencies)
  return data
}
```

`raw` only depends on the `dependencies` array and `expensiveMath` only depends on `raw` which means it only depends on the input arguments (`dependencies`).

I want to avoid calling `expensiveMath` when the input arguments have not changed.

But the problem is that I get this ESLint error:

ESLint error:

```
React Hook useMemo has a missing dependency: 'raw'. 
Either include it or remove the dependency array 
react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

I can't use `raw` as a dependency for `useMemo`, because it is a large array of complex objects with unpredictable length.

What is the best practice for my use-case?

Comment: Use `raw` as dependency. You're not cloning `raw`, you just pass the reference as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include `raw` in the dependencies then your code will not work, because `raw` is going to change when the fetch completes.

On the first render, `useFetch` is called and starts a request, and then returns some placeholder. If `useFetch` is [this library](https://use-http.com/#/), then that placeholder is an object with `loading: true` and `data: undefined`. Next `useMemo` runs, and does `expensiveMath` on that loading placeholder.

On the second render, `useFetch` is now done and returns the real data. But since `useMemo` doesn't list raw as a dependency, the memoized value is reused. You won't do `expensiveMath` on the real raw data.

So, the fix is to put `raw` in the dependency array:

```
const data = useMemo(
  () => expensiveMath(raw), 
  [raw]
)
```

Now `expensiveMath` will rerun when the fetch completes. I don't see any need to put `dependencies` into the useMemo, since they're not used in this part of the code.

> I can't use raw as a dependency for useMemo, because it is a large array of complex objects with unpredictable length.

The size doesn't matter. `useMemo` just does a reference equality check between the previous value and the new value. So as long as `useFetch` is written in a sensible way so that it returns stable references when nothing changed, it will work.